# Data inserted into MySQL through powershell script unexpectedly inserts two rows

Tags: mysql, powershell

I have working script to insert data like computer name, date, ip adress and two other data what my powershell script read from txt file.
I don't know why it makes double insert to mysql server where first insert is good and second don't have data from this txt file.

The script I've posted below successfully inserts data into my database however it seems to insert two separate rows.  One with the appropriate data in the End1 and End2 columns and one with incorrect data.

Code to capture and insert data:

```
$txt = "app_log.txt"
function find_nr {
        get-content $txt -ReadCount 1000 |
        foreach { $_ -match "P3#X" }
    }
    $string = find_nr
    $separator = "\;"
    function seperate {
        $string.Split($separator,6) 
    }
    function nr_lines {
        $i = 99901; seperate | % {$i++;"$($i-1) `t $_"}
    }
    function find {
        $line = $args[0]  | Select-String -Pattern "99905" -CaseSensitive 
        ($line.line.split(' ') |Where-Object {$_.Trim() -ne ''})[1]
    }
    function liczba {
        $result = nr_lines
        find $result
    } 
liczba

function find_sn {
    get-content $txt -ReadCount 1000 |
    foreach { $_ -match "P2#X" }
}
$string_sn = find_sn
$separator_sn = "\/"

function seperate_sn {
    $string_sn.Split($separator_sn,20)
}

function sn_lines {
    $i = 55501; seperate_sn | % {$i++;"$($i-1) `t $_"}
}

function find_sn {
    $line_sn = $args[0]  | Select-String -Pattern "55518" -CaseSensitive
    ($line_sn.line.split(' ') |Where-Object {$_.Trim() -ne ''})[1]
}

function sn {
$result2 = sn_lines
find_sn $result2
}
sn

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$name = $env:COMPUTERNAME 
$ipv4 = Test-Connection -ComputerName (hostname) -Count 1 | foreach { $_.ipv4address }
$time = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') 
$end1 = liczba 
$end2 = sn 

Start-Sleep -s 5

[string]$sMySQLUserName = 'user'
[string]$sMySQLPW = 'pass'
[string]$sMySQLDB = 'db'
[string]$sMySQLHost = '1.0.0.0'
[string]$sConnectionString = "server="+$sMySQLHost+";port=3306;uid=" + $sMySQLUserName + ";pwd=" + $sMySQLPW + ";database="+$sMySQLDB+";SslMode=none"

$oConnection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection($sConnectionString)
$Error.Clear()
try
{
    $oConnection.Open()
}
catch
{
    write-warning ("DB error: $sMySQLDB na ip:  $sMySQLHost. Error: "+$Error[0].ToString())
}

$oMYSQLCommand = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$oMYSQLCommand.CommandText="
INSERT into `db.scanner` (name,ipv4,date,raports,serialnumber) VALUES('$name','$ipv4','$time','$end1','$end2')"
$oMYSQLCommand.Connection=$oConnection
$oMYSQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
$oConnection.Close()
```

Script starts every 3rd day of the week at the user login.

This is how it looks in mysql db:

```
ID  NAME        IP      DATE                END1    END2
239 S02C-KASA1  1.0.0.1 2021-09-02 08:15:37 0   
238 S02C-KASA1  1.0.0.1 2021-09-02 08:15:37 1476    CAO1802176616FC
```

It appears the inserts are happening at the same time from the data.  Does anyone have an idea as to what is causing this?

Edit:
This is a app_log.txt data:

```
Send : P23#sae\
Resp.: ...P2#X0;1;0;1;1;2;20;9;29/23.00/08.00/05.00/00.00/100.00/101.00/101.00/0/0./0./0./0./0./0./0./29930676.49/BDS13287171EF\
Resp.: .

Send : P24#sa9\
Resp.: ..P3#X2015;2;10;1771;59;0;249.00/0.00/0.00/0.00/0.00/0.00/0.00/80\
Resp.: .
```

find_nr takes this line: `P3#X2015;2;10;1771;59;0;249.00/0.00/0.00/0.00/0.00/0.00/0.00/80\`

find_sn takes this line:
`P2#X0;1;0;1;1;2;20;9;29/23.00/08.00/05.00/00.00/100.00/101.00/101.00/0/0./0./0./0./0./0./0./29930676.49/BDS13287171EF\`

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting two rows.  I would suspect something outside of your powershell script is manipulating the data.

FYI your INSERT statement is inserting into the columns ```name,ipv4,date,raports,serialnumber``` but given your input and the example data is that correct or do you mean to be inserting into end1 and end2?

Comment: ID 238 is correct. ID 239 is wrong because this data from `app_log.txt` file has not changed in a sec. END1 and END2 should not be empty or null.

Comment: Now I get it. In my database it looks like You wrote: `name,ipv4,date,raports,serialnumber`. I'd just used END1 and END2 to show what data should be in the last two columns.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in your code.  Is there potentially something duplicated in your data?  Is find_nr  returning more than one line?  Perhaps share a sample of the data in the text file that relates to the rows being inserted.

Comment: I edited my post. You can check what app_log.txt have inside.

Comment: Does is post a duplicate for every insert or just certain ones?

Comment: Every insert where script start at user login. If the script is started manually theres no problem - insert have full data and it is single.

Comment: That makes me think there are two scheduled events or triggers on their machines.  Are there two versions of the script potentially being executed?  If it doesn't happen when run manually then it's not a problem with the script itself.

Comment: I added a procedure if $end1 is empty then break. Before MYSQL part of the script. `if ($end1 -eq $null){
Write-Output "No raports"
    break
    } else { ` Well... I tested this solution and I have no empty entries so far. Hope this will be enough :)